# Chamar evento de dentro do código

Tags: c#

Tenho esse evento em meu código:

```
protected void rdbGarantiaConfissao_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Declarações
            RadioButtonList vrblAprovado = sender as RadioButtonList;
            try
            {
                //Instâncias e Inicializações

                //Desenvolvimento
                if (vrblAprovado.SelectedValue == "1")
                    MostraConfissaoGarantia(1);
                else
                    MostraConfissaoGarantia(2);
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Mensagem = (wucMensagens)Page.Master.FindControl("wucMasterMensagens");
                Mensagem.ExibirMensagem(wucMensagens.TipoAlerta.Erro, Ex.Source, Ex.Message, Ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
```

Como eu faço para em outra parte do código eu executar esse evento?

Só quero evitar isso:

```
if (rdbGarantiaConfissao.SelectedValue == "1")
   wucCadastroConfissaoDividaPV.Visible = true;
else
   wucGarantiaAdicionalPV.Visible = true;
```

Pois o evento SelectedIndexChanged já faz isso, como pode ser visto.

Comment: Que outra parte do código? Seja específico.

Comment: Chame o método da forma como faz com qualquer outro. Passe um `RadioButtonList`. O parâmetro `EventArgs` pode ser null.

Comment: Eu quero chamar o SelectedIndex do meu Radiobuttolist, de outro método.

Comment: Dentro desta mesma classe? É preciso saber exatamente quem vai chamá-lo para chamar do jeito correto (e ver se pode chamar).

Comment: O sender é o seu `Radiobuttolist`

Comment: Mas quem é o `Radiobuttolist`? Se o método está protegido você só pode chamar dentro desta classe ou de uma que herde desta.

Comment: seja mais específico, aonde voce quer chamar esse metodo, esse RadioButtoList tem metodo onchange ?

Comment: @pnet, a chamada será feita da mesma Classe (Page ou UserControl) ou de outra Pagina ou UserControl?

Comment: @bigown nesse caso o `Radiobuttolist` é `this`

Comment: @ramaral É o que eu acho mas não tenho certeza.

Comment: Tudo está na mesma classe.

Answer (score 1):

Assim resolveu:

```
protected void rdbGarantiaConfissao_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           NomeMetodo(sender);
        }

private void NomeMetodo(object sender){
 //Declarações
            RadioButtonList vrblAprovado = sender as RadioButtonList;
            try
            {
                //Instâncias e Inicializações

                //Desenvolvimento
                if (vrblAprovado.SelectedValue == "1")
                    MostraConfissaoGarantia(1);
                else
                    MostraConfissaoGarantia(2);
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Mensagem = (wucMensagens)Page.Master.FindControl("wucMasterMensagens");
                Mensagem.ExibirMensagem(wucMensagens.TipoAlerta.Erro, Ex.Source, Ex.Message, Ex.StackTrace);
            }
}

protected void NomeEvento2(){
   NomeMetodo(rdbGarantiaConfissao);
}
```

Comment: Não percebo por que não usa simplesmente: `rdbGarantiaConfissao_SelectedIndexChanged(this, null);`

Comment: Não pensei nisso. O this seria meu sender, certo?

Comment: Sim. Claro que isto só é válido porque a chamada é feita na própria classe, também não seria possível de outro modo já que o método é `protected`

Answer (score 0):

Tente usando Eventhandler

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.eventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Ou crie um método que use RadioButton como parâmetro.

```
  protected void rdbGarantiaConfissao_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//Chame o metodo
             Metodo(meuradiobtn);
     }
```

Comment: Você tem certeza que isto responde a pergunta?

Comment: não, em realidade o evento funciona. Tanto funciona, que eu quero agora executá-lo fora, só para não que ficar fazendo if com ele. Já fiz isso uma vez em outra empresa e não me lembro como foi feito.

Answer (score 0):

Se você pretende utilizar somente a propriedade `SelectedValue` do `RadioButtonList`, você pode criar um método que recebe um parâmetro do tipo *String*, algo assim:

```
protected void MeuMetodo(String selectedValue) 
{
    try
    {
        //Instâncias e Inicializações

        //Desenvolvimento
        if (selectedValue == "1")
            MostraConfissaoGarantia(1);
        else
            MostraConfissaoGarantia(2);
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        Mensagem = (wucMensagens)Page.Master.FindControl("wucMasterMensagens");
        Mensagem.ExibirMensagem(wucMensagens.TipoAlerta.Erro, Ex.Source, Ex.Message, Ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

Para utilizar esse método no evento `SelectedIndexChanged` ou em qualquer outra parte do código, você pode fazer algo assim:

```
protected void rdbGarantiaConfissao_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButtonList vrblAprovado = sender as RadioButtonList;
    if (vrblAprovado != null)
        MeuMetodo(vrblAprovado.SelectedValue);
    else
        // o que você irá fazer se sender não for do tipo RadioButtonList
}

protected void QualquerOutroMetodoQueVoceTem()
{
    MeuMetodo(SeuRadioButtonList.SelectedValue);
}
```

Caso você precise realmente trabalhar com mais informações que estão no `RadioButtonList`, pode fazer assim:

```
protected void MeuMetodo(RadioButtonList radioButtonList) 
{
    try
    {
        //Instâncias e Inicializações

        //Desenvolvimento
        if (radioButtonList.SelectedValue == "1")
            MostraConfissaoGarantia(1);
        else
            MostraConfissaoGarantia(2);
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        Mensagem = (wucMensagens)Page.Master.FindControl("wucMasterMensagens");
        Mensagem.ExibirMensagem(wucMensagens.TipoAlerta.Erro, Ex.Source, Ex.Message, Ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

E para chamá-lo:

```
protected void rdbGarantiaConfissao_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButtonList vrblAprovado = sender as RadioButtonList;
    if (vrblAprovado != null)
        MeuMetodo(vrblAprovado);
    else
        // o que você irá fazer se sender não for do tipo RadioButtonList
}

protected void QualquerOutroMetodoQueVoceTem()
{
    MeuMetodo(SeuRadioButtonList);
}
```

Note que o "tratamento" das exceções é feito dentro do `MeuMetodo`, aqui no SOpt tem algumas perguntas que tratam desse assunto.